# How to overcome the situation when content of spinner is hidden?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, sqlite

I created an android application that takes some data using editText field such as Name, Contact, one radiogroup button, two buttons for save and view stored data and a spinner and stores these information in database when save button is pressed. Datas are displayed at the bottom of the screen when view button is pressed.Usually the spinner shows value 18 as by default.Everything is fine,when I open the application and press save button after entering the fields it saves and when once view button is pressed datas are displayed but I can not insert more data by opening the application once because the content of spinner is hidden now. To do that I need to close the application and then open it once again. How to overcome this problem. Anyone plz run the codes and see what is the problem

.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textContcat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/namehint"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/age"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spAge"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textContcat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/contact"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editContact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/contacthint"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sx"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/RadioGroup01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/malebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/mal"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/femalebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/femal"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/savebutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewbutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/view"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSQLinfo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/nullvalue"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

.java file:

```
public class SqlLiteExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
OnItemSelectedListener {
Button sqlUpdate, sqlView;
EditText etName, etContact;
RadioGroup myRadioGrp;
RadioButton rbtn1, rbtn2;
Spinner sp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.sqlliteexample);
sqlUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
etContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editContact);
rbtn1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.malebutton);
rbtn2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.femalebutton);
sqlView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewbutton);
sqlView.setOnClickListener(this);
sqlUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);

uI();
spElements();

}

private void spElements() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
List<String> ages = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 18; i <= 99; i++) {
    ages.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
// Creating adapter for spinner
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ages);
// Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
dataAdapter
        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// attaching data adapter to spinner
sp.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

private void uI() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spAge);
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (arg0.getId()) {
case R.id.savebutton:
    boolean didWork = true;
    try {
        String name = etName.getText().toString();
        String age = (String) sp.getSelectedItem();
        String contact = etContact.getText().toString();

        myRadioGrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup01);
        String sex = ((RadioButton) this.findViewById(myRadioGrp
                .getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();

        MyDB entry = new MyDB(SqlLiteExample.this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(name, age, contact, sex);
        entry.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        didWork = false;
        String error = e.toString();
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("Error");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(error);
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
    } finally {
        if (didWork) {
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Updated");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("Succesfully");
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }
    }
    break;
case R.id.viewbutton:
    Intent i = new Intent("com.bysakiralam.mydatabase.DISPLAYRECORDS");
    startActivity(i);
    break;
}
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> main, View arg1, int position,
    long Id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}

Displayrecords.java :

public class DisplayRecords extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sqlliteexample);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSQLinfo);
    MyDB info = new MyDB(this);

    try {
        info.open();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    tv.setText(data);
}

}
```

MyDB.java :

```
public class MyDB {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "persons_name";
public static final String KEY_AGE = "persons_age";
public static final String KEY_CONTACT = "persons_contact";
public static final String KEY_SEX = "gender";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "peopleTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_SEX
                + " TEXT NOT NULL)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public MyDB(Context c) {
    ourContext = c;
}

public MyDB open() throws SQLException {
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String name, String age, String contact, String sex) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_AGE, age);
    cv.put(KEY_CONTACT, contact);
    cv.put(KEY_SEX, sex);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_AGE,
            KEY_CONTACT, KEY_SEX };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    int iAGE = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AGE);
    int iCONTACT = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTACT);
    int iSEX = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SEX);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + "\t\t" + c.getString(iName)
                + "\t" + c.getString(iAGE) + "\t\t" + c.getString(iCONTACT)
                + "\t" + c.getString(iSEX) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to reset the spinner once you save or view an entry? (Perhaps in the onClick methods of the save/view buttons)
Also the xml file doesn't seem right as you have a Linear Layout within a ScrollView.

Comment: what should be the xml file...can you plz help.?

Comment: how to reset spinner in onClick method.. I used spinner.setSelection(position) but not working.

Comment: The Linear Layout should come first then the ScrollView then the rest.
Also close the </LinearLayout at the end of the xml file>